# como corrijo este error? Es necesario el administrador de espacios de nombres o XsltContext. Esta consulta tiene un prefijo

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, xml

tengo este xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Version="3.3" Total="7715.19" TipoDeComprobante="I" TipoCambio="1" SubTotal="6651.02" Serie="ABI" Sello="NIu9yhXoaJdJ8EJAO9TlMTY2NSMysG0hOT70BR01OZXjwHqjEs4F943OwBpnsmbDpUZ4xPdCRzNfe7eIfZJIDpIxlY+nyNTQuh0SKHUsh51vtyiBvkHRyQ5f9C5RlUGeiIKgMpotlo8i8hIv0jR46iUTO//7ZVBI+VFgl/G5yHPMB+A+HoyqssnvZlTfaF0CF+DGSIDHX1Jva1GVUIIoHy8fcUYVLFdr4km+kFeA/VKq06sZK47C0GhJ43F1FfsMxdc0U0TktbBl37kk60RdBBksbrZDlOy7JiAggjthY/7FvEnPYmceeZ4m5DlvQYbYFm2A4lNslC0tPKX9NBQTEw==" NoCertificado="00001000000501321059" Moneda="MXN" MetodoPago="PPD" LugarExpedicion="08610" FormaPago="99" Folio="19411" Fecha="2020-01-14T00:00:00" Certificado="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">

<cfdi:Emisor Rfc="SWI5210141J5" RegimenFiscal="601" Nombre="CIA SHERWIN WILLIAMS SA DE CV"/>

<cfdi:Receptor Rfc="CPA860306F97" Nombre="CONSTRUCTORA PASVOR, S.A DE C.V." UsoCFDI="G01"/>


-<cfdi:Conceptos>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="21.86" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="AP7101" Importe="109.30" Descripcion="TWO PACK FELPA PARA MINI RODILLO DE NYLON" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211906" Cantidad="5">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="17.49" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="109.30"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="2018.38" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="F75YJ28-19" Importe="2018.38" Descripcion="F75 ESMALTE METALEX AMARILLO CROMO" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211505" Cantidad="1">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="322.94" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="2018.38"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="2018.36" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="F75CJ30-19" Importe="2018.36" Descripcion="METALEX AZUL MINUSVALIDOS" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211505" Cantidad="1">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="322.94" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="2018.36"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="2018.38" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="F75WJ26-19" Importe="2018.38" Descripcion="F75 METALEX BLANCO ACABADO" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211505" Cantidad="1">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="322.94" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="2018.38"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="243.30" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="R02KA04-G" Importe="486.60" Descripcion="REDUCTOR 73" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211604" Cantidad="2">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="77.86" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="486.60"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>

</cfdi:Conceptos>


-<cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="1064.17">


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="1064.17" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Complemento>

<tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" SelloSAT="dKZgn49JIAMJmEwLypvimLD6ZgQ7ifyjrVCxMM42aaiEy2fPMI2eFjLY+C20bPEIoeWrJStTP9aviKoJ4PDy1K6da17qvfca/Kl0J+agpVkpK/fz8P2/OGfRXguS8KD04ud+Mccjot2sy3tImOebC11zQzkOqz6Z344MkUjbi101YQj7nZYLqo1GptzPfyUMgRWOQ2apXA2QZoAkg+RFX5J+U1sgk3oSBao6V0qNF5C1HwvQnJyoQH75JDtEGE5/tyNPuU74e2E7uYkkVHw+6SFIeHRct8lAdL+H5OWk0I66TPROwssPLjMh3V6PREBtxmTYibq9FsdBv/Npe7OtKw==" NoCertificadoSAT="00001000000404627119" RfcProvCertif="STO020301G28" FechaTimbrado="2020-01-14T12:43:49" UUID="BF610644-DA37-47F4-B14C-548BC2A92853" SelloCFD="NIu9yhXoaJdJ8EJAO9TlMTY2NSMysG0hOT70BR01OZXjwHqjEs4F943OwBpnsmbDpUZ4xPdCRzNfe7eIfZJIDpIxlY+nyNTQuh0SKHUsh51vtyiBvkHRyQ5f9C5RlUGeiIKgMpotlo8i8hIv0jR46iUTO//7ZVBI+VFgl/G5yHPMB+A+HoyqssnvZlTfaF0CF+DGSIDHX1Jva1GVUIIoHy8fcUYVLFdr4km+kFeA/VKq06sZK47C0GhJ43F1FfsMxdc0U0TktbBl37kk60RdBBksbrZDlOy7JiAggjthY/7FvEnPYmceeZ4m5DlvQYbYFm2A4lNslC0tPKX9NBQTEw=="/>

</cfdi:Complemento>


-<cfdi:Addenda>


-<DSCargaRemisionProvInd xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DSCargaRemisionProvInd.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


-<Remision RowOrder="0" Id="Remision0">

<Proveedor>334581</Proveedor>

<FolioPedido>3723233</FolioPedido>

</Remision>

</DSCargaRemisionProvInd>

</cfdi:Addenda>

</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

quiero obtener el dato del total, nombre, rfc, folio, subtotal pero al llegar a esta línea

```
m_nodelist3 = m_xmld3.SelectNodes("/cfdi:Comprobante")
```

me manda ese error, este es mi código a ver si le entienden jeje

```
Private Sub btnExaminar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExaminar.Click
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        txtFactura.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName()
    End If
    'convertir xml a string
    Dim xmldoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    xmldoc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim allText As String = xmldoc.InnerXml
    '-------------------------------
    Dim objXml As New servicioXmlSinAddenda.wseDocRecibo
    'cargar Xml como string
    Dim respuesta As String
    respuesta = objXml.RecibeCFD_SinAddenda(allText.ToString())
    '------------------
    Try
        Dim m_xmld2 As XmlDocument
        Dim m_nodelist2 As XmlNodeList
        Dim m_node2 As XmlNode

        'Creamos el "Document"
        m_xmld2 = New XmlDocument()

        'Cargamos el archivo
        m_xmld2.LoadXml(respuesta)

        'Obtenemos la lista de los nodos "errorDescription"
        m_nodelist2 = m_xmld2.SelectNodes("/AckErrorApplication/messageError/errorDescription")

        'Iniciamos el ciclo de lectura
        For Each m_node2 In m_nodelist2

            'Obtenemos el Elemento texto
            mText = m_node2.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText

            'Escribimos el resultado en la consola, 
            'pero tambien podriamos utilizarlos en
            'donde deseemos
            Console.Write("mText: " & mText)
            'Console.Write(vbCrLf)

        Next

        '----------------
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error trapping
        Console.Write(ex.ToString())
    End Try
    'leer datos del xml
    Try
        Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
        Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim m_node As XmlNode

        'Creamos el "Document"
        m_xmld = New XmlDocument()

        'Cargamos el archivo
        m_xmld.LoadXml(respuesta)

        'Obtenemos la lista de los nodos "name"
        m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/AckErrorApplication")

        'Iniciamos el ciclo de lectura
        For Each m_node In m_nodelist
            'Obtenemos el atributo del documentStatus
            Dim mdocumentStatus = m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("documentStatus").Value
            '------------------
            If mdocumentStatus = "ACCEPTED" Then
                'obtenemos los datos del xml original
                Try
                    Dim m_xmld3 As XmlDocument
                    Dim m_nodelist3 As XmlNodeList
                    Dim m_node3 As XmlNode
                    Dim BaseImp As String = String.Empty

                    'Creamos el "Document"
                    m_xmld3 = New XmlDocument()

                    'Cargamos el archivo
                    m_xmld3.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName)

                    'Obtenemos la lista de los nodos "name"
                    m_nodelist3 = m_xmld3.SelectNodes("/cfdi:Comprobante")

                    'Iniciamos el ciclo de lectura
                    For Each m_node3 In m_nodelist
                        'Obtenemos el atributo del codigo
                        lblTotFact.Text = m_node3.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Total").Value
                        txtNomProv.Text = m_node3.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Nombre").Value
                        txtProv.Text = m_node3.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Rfc").Value
                        txtFolioFact.Text = m_node3.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Folio").Value
                        txtImporte.Text = m_node3.Attributes.GetNamedItem("SubTotal").Value - CDec(lblDescuento.Text) + CDec(ImpIep)

                        lblDescuento.Text = frmDetalleCompCargo.pDescuento
                        If Decimal.Parse(BaseImp) = 0 Then
                            cboTasaIVA.SelectedIndex = cboTasaIVA.FindString("EXCENTO 0%")
                            cboTasaIVA.Enabled = False
                        End If

                        If Decimal.Parse(BaseImp) = 0.16 Then
                            cboTasaIVA.SelectedIndex = cboTasaIVA.FindString("Iva 16")
                            cboTasaIVA.Enabled = False
                        End If

                        If Decimal.Parse(BaseImp) = 0.08 Then
                            cboTasaIVA.SelectedIndex = cboTasaIVA.FindString("Iva 8")
                            cboTasaIVA.Enabled = False
                        End If

                        If Decimal.Parse(BaseImp) = 0.11 Then
                            cboTasaIVA.SelectedIndex = cboTasaIVA.FindString("Iva 11")
                            cboTasaIVA.Enabled = False
                        End If
                        txtRetencion.Text = Retencion

                        Console.Write("mdocumentStatus: " & mdocumentStatus)
                        'Console.Write(vbCrLf)

                    Next
                    '----------------
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'Error trapping
                    Console.Write(ex.ToString())
                End Try
            ElseIf mdocumentStatus = "REJECT" Then
                MessageBox.Show(mText.ToString())
            End If
            '--------------
            Console.Write("mdocumentStatus: " & mdocumentStatus)
            'Console.Write(vbCrLf)

        Next
        '----------------
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error trapping
        Console.Write(ex.ToString())
    End Try
    '----------------------



End Sub
```

quiero saber porque me manda ese error, como debo poner el tag del `xml`? ya intenté de varia maneras de poner el tag `/cfdi:Comprobante`, cual es la manera correcta, si se fijan en otras partes del código traigo datos de otro xml y ahí si funciona pero aquí no, tiene algo que ver los `:`?

Answer (score 1):

Tu XML esta mal armado esos guiones que se ven al empezar las lineas `-` quiere decir que lo copiaste de un navegador, pero no le diste `clic derecho`->`ver código fuente de la pagina`.

Comment: ok pero no encuentro donde editarlo

Comment: En el navegador clic derecho->ver código fuente de la pagina y guarda el que sale en código fuente de la pagina.

Comment: ya lo resolví asi:

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolví asi:

```
Dim m_xmld3 As XmlDocument
Dim m_nodelist3 As XmlNodeList
Dim m_node3 As XmlNode
Dim BaseImp As String = String.Empty
Dim nm As XmlNamespaceManager

'Creamos el "Document"
m_xmld3 = New XmlDocument()
nm = New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld3.NameTable)
nm.AddNamespace("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3")

'Cargamos el archivo
m_xmld3.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName)

'Obtenemos la lista de los nodos "name"
m_nodelist3 = m_xmld3.SelectNodes("/cfdi:Comprobante", nm)
                                                                                                                                            aunque /cfdi:Comprobante solo me sirve para los atributos de ese tag, si lo pongo asi /cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Emisor solo me trae los atributos de cfdi:Emisor, hay forma de ponerlo que me traiga los atributos de los 2 tags sino pues hago otro try catch igual para traer los otros atributos
```

Comment: aunque /cfdi:Comprobante solo me sirve para los atributos de ese tag, si lo pongo asi /cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Emisor solo me trae los atributos de cfdi:Emisor, hay forma de ponerlo que me traiga los atributos de los 2 tags sino pues hago otro try catch igual para traer los otros atributos

Answer (score 0):

ok ya hice otro try catch para los otros datos pero ahora tengo otro problema, como le hago para obtener el texto de un atributo en un nodo hijo por ejemplo quiero obtener el importe 49.34 del xml, ya ven que para traer el valor de un atributo es asi:

txtIVA.Text = m_node5.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Importe").Value

y para el texto de un nodo hijo es asi:

txtIVA.Text = m_node5.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText

ahora quiero traer el valor de un atributo de un nodo hijo, pero esa cantidad de 49.34 puede venir en un renglón o en varios como aquí

de este xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Version="3.3" Total="7715.19" TipoDeComprobante="I" TipoCambio="1" SubTotal="6651.02" Serie="ABI" Sello="NIu9yhXoaJdJ8EJAO9TlMTY2NSMysG0hOT70BR01OZXjwHqjEs4F943OwBpnsmbDpUZ4xPdCRzNfe7eIfZJIDpIxlY+nyNTQuh0SKHUsh51vtyiBvkHRyQ5f9C5RlUGeiIKgMpotlo8i8hIv0jR46iUTO//7ZVBI+VFgl/G5yHPMB+A+HoyqssnvZlTfaF0CF+DGSIDHX1Jva1GVUIIoHy8fcUYVLFdr4km+kFeA/VKq06sZK47C0GhJ43F1FfsMxdc0U0TktbBl37kk60RdBBksbrZDlOy7JiAggjthY/7FvEnPYmceeZ4m5DlvQYbYFm2A4lNslC0tPKX9NBQTEw==" NoCertificado="00001000000501321059" Moneda="MXN" MetodoPago="PPD" LugarExpedicion="08610" FormaPago="99" Folio="19411" Fecha="2020-01-14T00:00:00" Certificado="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">

<cfdi:Emisor Rfc="SWI5210141J5" RegimenFiscal="601" Nombre="CIA SHERWIN WILLIAMS SA DE CV"/>

<cfdi:Receptor Rfc="CPA860306F97" Nombre="CONSTRUCTORA PASVOR, S.A DE C.V." UsoCFDI="G01"/>


-<cfdi:Conceptos>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="21.86" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="AP7101" Importe="109.30" Descripcion="TWO PACK FELPA PARA MINI RODILLO DE NYLON" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211906" Cantidad="5">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="17.49" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="109.30"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="2018.38" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="F75YJ28-19" Importe="2018.38" Descripcion="F75 ESMALTE METALEX AMARILLO CROMO" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211505" Cantidad="1">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="322.94" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="2018.38"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="2018.36" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="F75CJ30-19" Importe="2018.36" Descripcion="METALEX AZUL MINUSVALIDOS" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211505" Cantidad="1">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="322.94" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="2018.36"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="2018.38" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="F75WJ26-19" Importe="2018.38" Descripcion="F75 METALEX BLANCO ACABADO" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211505" Cantidad="1">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="322.94" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="2018.38"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>


-<cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="243.30" Unidad="EA" NoIdentificacion="R02KA04-G" Importe="486.60" Descripcion="REDUCTOR 73" ClaveUnidad="H87" ClaveProdServ="31211604" Cantidad="2">


-<cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="77.86" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002" Base="486.60"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>

</cfdi:Concepto>

</cfdi:Conceptos>


-<cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="1064.17">


-<cfdi:Traslados>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="0.00" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.000000" Impuesto="002"/>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="49.34" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Impuesto="002"/>

<cfdi:Traslado Importe="7.30" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.080000" Impuesto="003"/>

</cfdi:Traslados>

</cfdi:Impuestos>


-<cfdi:Complemento>

<tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" SelloSAT="dKZgn49JIAMJmEwLypvimLD6ZgQ7ifyjrVCxMM42aaiEy2fPMI2eFjLY+C20bPEIoeWrJStTP9aviKoJ4PDy1K6da17qvfca/Kl0J+agpVkpK/fz8P2/OGfRXguS8KD04ud+Mccjot2sy3tImOebC11zQzkOqz6Z344MkUjbi101YQj7nZYLqo1GptzPfyUMgRWOQ2apXA2QZoAkg+RFX5J+U1sgk3oSBao6V0qNF5C1HwvQnJyoQH75JDtEGE5/tyNPuU74e2E7uYkkVHw+6SFIeHRct8lAdL+H5OWk0I66TPROwssPLjMh3V6PREBtxmTYibq9FsdBv/Npe7OtKw==" NoCertificadoSAT="00001000000404627119" RfcProvCertif="STO020301G28" FechaTimbrado="2020-01-14T12:43:49" UUID="BF610644-DA37-47F4-B14C-548BC2A92853" SelloCFD="NIu9yhXoaJdJ8EJAO9TlMTY2NSMysG0hOT70BR01OZXjwHqjEs4F943OwBpnsmbDpUZ4xPdCRzNfe7eIfZJIDpIxlY+nyNTQuh0SKHUsh51vtyiBvkHRyQ5f9C5RlUGeiIKgMpotlo8i8hIv0jR46iUTO//7ZVBI+VFgl/G5yHPMB+A+HoyqssnvZlTfaF0CF+DGSIDHX1Jva1GVUIIoHy8fcUYVLFdr4km+kFeA/VKq06sZK47C0GhJ43F1FfsMxdc0U0TktbBl37kk60RdBBksbrZDlOy7JiAggjthY/7FvEnPYmceeZ4m5DlvQYbYFm2A4lNslC0tPKX9NBQTEw=="/>

</cfdi:Complemento>


-<cfdi:Addenda>


-<DSCargaRemisionProvInd xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DSCargaRemisionProvInd.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


-<Remision RowOrder="0" Id="Remision0">

<Proveedor>334581</Proveedor>

<FolioPedido>3723233</FolioPedido>

</Remision>

</DSCargaRemisionProvInd>

</cfdi:Addenda>

</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Comment: finalmente lo hice así

 For Each m_node5 In m_nodelist5
                            'Obtenemos el atributo del codigo

                            If m_node5.Attributes.GetNamedItem("TasaOCuota").Value = BaseImp Then
                                txtIVA.Text = m_node5.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Importe").Value
                            End If
                            'txtIVA.Text = m_node5.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText

                        Next
gracias por responder